# post request works in postman but not in php

Tags: php, curl, post, http-post, postman

Those are the parameters in the postman:

POST URL:

```
https://rest-api.wm.com/user/authenticate
```

Headers:

```
apikey: 6277FF29BB19666078AC
content-type: application/json
```

body: (username and pass are incorrect in the next example)

{"username":"xxx@xxx.com","password":"xxx","locale":"en_US"}

and as a result, I received a JSON page that confirms that I logged on in the website.

But when i conver this code into PHP

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://rest-api.wm.com/user/authenticate",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"{\"username\":\"xxx@xxx.com\",\"password\":\"xxx\",\"locale\":\"en_US\"}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "apikey:  6277FF29BB19666078AC",
    "content-type:  application/json",
    "Content-Type: text/plain"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

And this is not working when I start the script I received this error:

```
{"status":"failed","errorMsg":"Please enter valid input","statusCode":400}
```

Very strange how this cna work in the postman and not in the PHP, any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add "Content-Length" to CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER:

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      "apikey:  6277FF29BB19666078AC",
      "Content-Type: application/json",
      "Content-Length: " . strlen($json))
 ),
```

You need string length of you json.